# Mysql. Проверить связь

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица `comments` и `users`.  Есть связь по `comments.userid` и `users.id`. Нужно определить все Коментарии у которых авторы`(comment.userid)` не существуют. Направьте примерно какой запрос нужно строить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выберет все комментарии которые не имеют пользователя

```
select * from comments c
left join users u on u.id = c.user_id
where u.id is null
```